# Can adb shell work in binary mode?

Tags: adb, shell

`adb shell` sends \r\n instead of \n. Can I tell `adb` to not change the datastream (just like I can with `ssh`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but:

The linebreak conversion is **not** done by ADB, but your host system (and its console host), Windows.

This issue has already been discussed on SO, and there are a few posts providing possible solutions. Here are some of them

- Stack Overflow: [Read binary stdout data from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416)
- This site (Android.SE): [Is it possible to cat a file to an android phone and dd to /dev/xxx on the fly with just adb shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69434)

Comment: If it is done by GNU/Linux, why can I not do: 'adb shell cat binaryfile > localfile' and have localfile be the same as binaryfile?